# What does 誰も do in this sentence, and is it needed?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

「日本語で話し相手が誰もいませんでした。」

"I didn't have anyone to speak Japanese with."

I feel like 誰も is unnecessary. As far as I can tell, 「日本語で話し相手がいませんでした。」 has every element needed to express the English above. What nuance is lost if you cut out 誰も?

Answer (score 3):

I feel like it’s a difference between “I didn’t have a partner to speak Japanese with” and “I didn’t have anyone as partner to speak Japanese with”. So 誰も and “anyone” emphasise the fact that there was really no-one.

Comment: Agreed - it's a means of adding emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

Question words + も ＋ negative／positive expressions means "**totally** negative/positive"

> どちら も 正しいです

Both is right.( No matter which one, is right)

> 誰 も 来なかったんです

No one came. ( No matter who, no came)

Comment: Related question, as I read your answers -- why is 誰も not marked with a particle in the example?

Comment: @charlemagne It is marked. 誰 is the question word, も is the particle, も is like the が combined with 'also, or too' in simple words.

Comment: なるほど。 I've been thinking of 誰も as a single word. Thanks.